# How to hardcode long strings in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing a macro to save VBA modules as 64 bit strings in another self-extracting module. The self-extracting module is designed to hold several long strings (could be any length, up to the max 2GB strings I suppose), and a few short snippets of code to decompress the strings and import the modules they represent.

Anyway, when my macro builds the self extracting module it needs to save the really long strings (I'm saving as hardcoded `Const`s). But if they are too long (>1024 ish) to fit on a single line in the VBA editor, I get errors.

How should I format these hardcoded strings so that I can save them either as `Const`s or in another way in my self-extracting module? So far I've been saving each string as several `Const` declarations in 1000 character chunks, but it would be preferable to have one string per item only.

Comment: Using line-continuation character `_` you are able to concatenate string constants up to 15188 chars length. Also consider `CustomXMLParts` instead of inline values.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comment, you can use custom XML part to store information inside the workbook.

Here’s the code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AddCustomPart()

    Dim oXmlPart    As CustomXMLPart
    Dim strTest     As String

    strTest = "<Test_ID>123456</Test_ID>"

    Set oXmlPart = ReadCustomPart("Test_ID")

    '/ Check if there is already an elemnt available with same name.
    '/ VBA or Excel Object Model, doesn't perevnt duplicate entries.
    If oXmlPart Is Nothing Then
        Set oXmlPart = ThisWorkbook.CustomXMLParts.Add(strTest)
    Else
        MsgBox oXmlPart.DocumentElement.Text
    End If

End Sub

Function ReadCustomPart(strTest As String) As CustomXMLPart

    Dim oXmlPart    As CustomXMLPart

    For Each oXmlPart In ThisWorkbook.CustomXMLParts
        If Not oXmlPart.DocumentElement Is Nothing Then
            If oXmlPart.SelectSingleNode("/*").BaseName = strTest Then
                Set ReadCustomPart = oXmlPart
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Set ReadCustomPart = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Doesn't this still face the problem of writing long strings when I specify what `strTest` must equal?

Comment: Put that string a txt file and then read it from there and embed as custom XML.